# how can select before and after selected text in jquery

Tags: jquery, text, input

I want find text before and after selected text in text box

for example

```
<input id="selectionBox" />
```

Example:
selectionBox input value is equal to "Check the address for typing..."

user selected "r" after "Check the add" and before "ess for typing..." and i wanna store before and after "r" in separate variable

```
$('#selectionBox').select(function(e) { 
    var start = e.target.selectionStart;
    var end = e.target.selectionEnd;
    var selectedtext  = $('#selectionBox').val().substring(start, end);
    // find before and after selected text  
    //var beforeSel = before selection;
    //var afterSel = after selection;
})
```

EDIT 1:
I want find before and after text for change selctionBox value like this

```
var textboxValue = beforeSel + "<blank>" + selectedtext  + "<blank>" + afterSel;
$("#selectionBox").val(textboxValue);
```

how can do that? thank you

Comment: How it should work if you will have few equal characters? If user select "e" ?

Comment: I edited my question please review that, thanks

Comment: First get the length of #('selectionBox').val(). then you can use substring() method to get all three values

Comment: [is this what you're trying to do?](http://jsfiddle.net/hgxw8faf/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use the same technique you used to get the selected text.

Use `substring(0, start)` to get the text before the selection, and `substring(end)` to get the text after the selection.

```js
$('#selectionBox').select(function(e) {
  var start = e.target.selectionStart;
  var end = e.target.selectionEnd;
  var text = $('#selectionBox').val();
  
  var selectedtext = text.substring(start, end);
  
  // find before and after selected text
  var beforeSel = text.substring(0, start);
  var afterSel = text.substring(end);

  $('#selected-text').text(selectedtext);
  $('#before-selection').text(beforeSel);
  $('#after-selection').text(afterSel);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="selectionBox" />
<div>Selected Text: <span id="selected-text" style="color:blue"></span>
</div>
<div>Before Selection: <span id="before-selection" style="color:blue"></span>
</div>
<div>After Selection: <span id="after-selection" style="color:blue"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @forgivenson